# Diff between (x=100) and { x=100; }?

Tags: shell, subshell

Can some one please explain the below statements?

> $ x=50
>
> $ (x=100) #here the code executes only with in the subshell. when subshellexecution done then the x value is returned to its original value, i.e. 50
>
> $ echo $x
>
> $ 50

---

> $ x=50
>
> $ { x=100; } #here the x value totaly changes and affecting to the current shell value of x and changes it from 50 to 100
>
> $ echo $x
>
> $ 100

---

how these are happening, Can some one explain?

Answer (score 3):

In Bourne-like shells, `( ... )` executes the code in a subshell, thus any change in the variables is local to this subshell, and not visible in the parent shell. On the contrary `{ ... }` executes code in the current shell, thus affecting its variables.

Answer (score 3):

From **man bash**:

> **(list)**   list  is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  *Variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do  not  remain  in  effect after the command completes.*
>
> **A command invoked in the separate environment cannot affect the shell's execution environment.**
>
> **{ list; }** list  is  simply executed in the current shell environment.

Answer (score 1):

As you said: `( )` causes a subshell. `{ ;}` doesn't. That's why the results differ. `{ ;}` doesn't make sense for single commands anyway. It's a grouping feature.